# SQLite: how to use PRAGMA application_id?

Tags: sqlite, pragma

While

```
PRAGMA application_id = <integer>;
```

does not fail, it seems it doesn't do a thing as

```
PRAGMA application_id;
```

always returns an empty set.

I tried over python (sqlite3 and APSW) and command line sqlite3(1)

note: I run debian's 3.7.13 version of sqlite

Answer (score 4):

The application_id was introduced in SQLite [3.7.17](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_17.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integer must be within the range of a signed 32-bit value (i.e. in the range -2<sup>32</sup> to +2<sup>32</sup>-1, which is -2147483648 to +2147483647). If the provided integer is out-of-range, then the statement will be accepted without error, however the application ID will be set to zero.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. The [documentation says "32-bit *unsigned* big-endian"](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_application_id) (emphasis mine), but for values between 2^31 and 2^32 − 1 it appears that you need to first subtract 2^32 lest the ID be set to zero. How did you determine this? Do you know why this is?

Comment: @wchargin I determined it by experimentation and guessing. I have no idea why this is. Since the documentation says *unsigned*, that does sound confusing.

Comment: I reported this to the mailing list: the documentation was in error, and was fixed in https://www.sqlite.org/docsrc/info/3580ba4b5bd75ec6. It now reads "32-bit signed big-endian".

Answer (score -1):

> PRAGMA application_id; 
>   PRAGMA application_id = integer ;
>   The application_id PRAGMA is used to query or set the 32-bit unsigned big-endian "Application ID" integer located at offset 68 into the database header. Applications that use SQLite as their application file-format should set the Application ID integer to a unique integer so that utilities such as file(1) can determine the specific file type rather than just reporting "SQLite3 Database". A list of assigned application IDs can be seen by consulting the magic.txt file in the SQLite source repository.

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_application_id